# Booting using initramfs instead of uramdisk

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, embedded, u-boot

I am working on Zynq Microzed board. It is booting perfectly with uramdisk.image.gz but I trying to boot it with initramfs.cpio.

In this regard I have made following changes in  header files of u-boot:

**zynq_common.h** and **zynq_common.h.save** changes are as follows

**"ramdisk_image=uramdisk.image.gz\0"**

to

**"ramdisk_image=initramfs.cpio\0"**

in both the header files

I am getting following log messages[image]

It is still looking for uramdisk.image.gz and giving an error

**Wrong Ramdisk Image Format**

**Ramdisk image is corrupt or invalid**

I am unable sought out where I am getting wrong and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you should convert it to u-boot file like this and give it a try:

```
mkimage -n 'Ramdisk Image'  -A arm -O linux -T ramdisk -C gzip -d initramfs.cpio.gz initramfs.uImage
```

This might be a valid format for u-boot.